# Series Solution to the ODE $(x-1)y'' - xy' + y = 0$ with I.C. $y(0) = -3$ and $y'(0)=4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align*}
(x-1)y'' - xy' + y = 0 &\iff (x-1)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)c_n x^{n-2} - x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nc_n x^{n-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n = 0 \\
&\iff \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)c_n x^{n-1} - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)c_n x^{n-2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nc_n x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n = 0 \\
&\iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (k+1)kc_{k+1} x^k - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2} x^k - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kc_k x^k + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k = 0 \\
&\iff -2c_2 + c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k \left[ k(k+1)c_{k+1} - (k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2} - kc_k + c_k \right] = 0 \\
\end{align*}
Therefore, $-2c_2 + c_0 = 0 \Rightarrow c_2 = \frac{c_0}{2!}$. And, 
$$c_{k+2} = \dfrac{c_k (1-k) + k(k+1)c_{k+1}}{(k+2)(k+1)}$$

To find the solution, first we let $c_0 = 1$ and $c_1 = 0$, then $c_2 = \frac{1}{2!}$. Then, for $k=1$ we have:
$$c_3 = \dfrac{2c_2}{3\cdot 2} = \dfrac{1}{3!}$$
For $k=2$ we have:
$$c_4 = \dfrac{-2c_2 + 6c_3}{4 \cdot 3} = \dfrac{1}{4!}$$
And the pattern continues so for this solution say $y_1$ we have:
$$y_1 = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + c_3 x^3 + \dots = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \dots = e^x - x$$
Now for $y_2$ we let $c_0 = 0$ and $c_1 = 1$, so that $c_2 = 0$ too. Then, we find that $c_3 = c_4 = \dots = 0$, so that 
$$y_2 = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + \dots = x$$
Then, the final solution should be $a_0 y_1 + a_1 y_2 = a_0 e^x + (a_1 - a_0)x$. However, from wolfram it says the solution is $y = a_0 e^x + a_1 e^{-x}$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your solution seems alright. In fact $e^{-x}$ isn't a solution to the ODE, so the general solution can't contain a multiple of it.

Comment: isn't $c_0=-3$ and $c_1=4$

Comment: It seems that you typed something wrong, as Wolfram yields a solution same to yours. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-1)y%27%27+-+xy%27+%2B+y+%3D+0

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima No, you're wrong. You have constrain on $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$, which aren't directly related to c's. So first you find the general solution and then you plug those values to find the particular one.

Comment: @Stefan4024 the solution is $y=c_0+c_1x+.... $

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima So how would you apply the condition on the infinite series?

Comment: @Stefan4024 $c_0=y (0)=-3$ and $c_1=y'(0)=4$. goodnight.

Comment: Mathematica gives $y=7 x-3 e^x$ so you are right

Answer (score 2):

**other approach**

The equation can be written as

$$(x-1)(y''-y')-(y'-y)=0$$
or
$$(x-1)z'-z=0$$
with $$z=y'-y $$

the solution is $$z=\lambda (x-1)=-7 (x-1) $$

Now look for series solution of

$$y'-y=-7 (x-1) $$

Answer (score 0):

This ODE belongs to the class which is dealt with in here [Yet another example of linear second order ODEs being reduced to hypergeometric functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939337/yet-another-example-of-linear-second-order-odes-being-reduced-to-hypergeometric/2939594#2939594) .

Using that approach we get the solution:

\begin{eqnarray}
y(x) &=& \exp(x/2) \sqrt{x-1} \left( C_1 W_{1/2,1}(x-1) + C_2 M_{1/2,1}(x-1) \right)\\
&=& (x-1)^2 \left( C_1 U(1,3,x-1) + C_2 F_{1,1}[1,3,x-1]\right)\\
&=& (x-1)^2 \left( C_1 \frac{e^{x-1} \Gamma(2,x-1)}{(x-1)^2} + C_2 \frac{2(e^{x-1}-x)}{(x-1)^2}\right)\\
&=& C_1 x + 2 C_2 (e^{x-1}-x)
\end{eqnarray}
Her $W_{\kappa,\mu}()$ and $M_{\kappa,\mu}()$ are the Whittaker functions and $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric function.